# Accessing HBase from inside Hadoop engine

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am doing some research related to Hadoop and I'm changing some of its internals. The problem I'm facing is: I want to access (read/write) HBase from the Task Tracker.

I tried to add HBase jar within Hadoop and re-compile and build Hadoop, but it is not compiling and it cannot find HBase functions. Did anyone knows how to do this? Do I need to change in the build files of Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

HBase client needs quite a few dependencies you need to add HBase to the pom file of your program (task tracker in your case)

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>${hbase.version} </version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I searched for the pom files, so should I add this dependency to hadoop-core-pom-template.xml or hadoop-client-pom-template.xml?

Comment: what version of hadoop are you trying to change? it might be a version that use ivy instead of maven.

Comment: It is version 0.20.0, and yes it uses ivy not maven. Thanks